# How to split string in pairs

Tags: excel, vba, string, split

I want to split in pairs the following string. With current code I'm only able to split the string in single characters.

```
Sub SplitinPair()
Dim str

    str = "5C61AA79"
    str = StrConv(str, vbUnicode)
    str = Left(str, Len(str) - 1)

    Debug.Print str
End Sub
```

The current output is

```
5 C 6 1 A A 7 9
```

and desired output I'm looking for is like this:

```
5C 61 AA 79
```

How to do this?

Comment: Hi, doing like you said doesn't work. I remove one character to remove unneeded trailing char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be a simple loop:

```
Private Sub SplitinPair()
   Dim str As String
   Dim str2 As String
   Dim i As Integer

   str = "5C61AA79"

   For i = 1 To Len(str) Step 2
      str2 = str2 & Mid(str, i, 2) & " "
   Next

   Debug.Print str2
End Sub
```

Comment: It works pretty fine. `Step 2` it seems to help a lot in this case. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This method assumes an even number of characters which would be the case with hex pairs. If there is a chance that you might encounter an odd numbered character set, add some error control.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitinPair()
    Dim str, tmp As Variant, i As Long

    str = "5C61AA79"
    str = StrConv(str, vbUnicode)

    tmp = Split(Left(str, Len(str) - 1), Chr(0))
    str = vbNullString

    For i = LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp) Step 2
        str = str & tmp(i) & tmp(i + 1) & Space(1)
    Next i

    str = Trim(str)

    Debug.Print str
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for share another solution. It works fine like you said when even number of characters.